# Получение результата работы PHP скрипта

Tags: php, java, android

Доброй ночи. Я написал PHP скрипт, который выводит данные в формате "0.0 0.0 name" (где 0.0 - координаты X и Y соответственно, а name - название). Это координаты архитектурных объектов, на которые мне нужно переключить рандомно первоначальное положение Google Maps. Скрипт работает отлично: он все выводит правильно, если перейти напрямую по ссылке его расположения. Однако мой код в Android Studio не принимает эти данные. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема:

```
public class GetMapPlace extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public String getMapPlace() {

    String line = "0.0 0.0 none";

    try {

        URL url = new URL(URL_GET_MAP); // подключаемся к интернету
        URLConnection connect = url.openConnection();
        connect.setDoOutput(true);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream())); // включаем буфер стандартного вывода, занося все в него (echo)
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        if (reader.readLine() != null) {
            builder.append(line); // получаем строку
        }

        Log.d("DEBUG", "ОТВЕТ" + line); // эта строка не отображается в логах
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return line;
} }
```

Помимо отсутствия строки DEBUG в логах, я пробовал вывести вручную значение line: оно всегда равно "0.0 0.0 none".

Вот как я в дальнейшем использую эти данные:

```
            GetMapPlace activity = new GetMapPlace();
            try {
                String line = activity.getMapPlace();
                Log.d("DEBUG", "ERROR123" + " " + line);

                String[] words = line.split(" ");
                position1 = Float.parseFloat(words[0]);
                position2 = Float.parseFloat(words[1]);
                name = words[3];
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // For dropping a marker at a point on the Map
            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(position1, position2);
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title(name).snippet("Marker Description"));

            // For zooming automatically to the location of the marker
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(sydney).zoom(12).build();
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

Буду рад любой помощи! С новым годом, господа!

Comment: С Новым 2019м! Как минимум подключение к Интернету должно быть в отдельном потоке.

Comment: Прошу прощения, а как это правильно сделать? Или.. Может пример есть какой-нибудь?

Comment: Документация. Гугл. ссылка на 1й же странице https://metanit.com/java/android/15.1.php (с объяснением).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, то у вас line инициализируется один раз в начале функции (`String line = "0.0 0.0 none";`) и впоследствии не изменяется. Видимо, надо сделать как-то так:

```
if ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    builder.append(line); // получаем строку
}
...
return builder.toString();
```

Ну а по поводу отсутствия DEBUG в логах - надо смотреть настройки логгера (вообще какой-либо debug попадает в логи?)

Comment: Тпак у меня же это есть...

Comment: у вас ```if (reader.readLine() != null)``` (т.е. строка читается, но локальной переменной не присваивается). а возвращаете из функции вы локальную переменную (видимо, полагая, что она должна быть изменена в процессе чтения данных).

Comment: можно вообще кардинально переписать фрагмент чтения данных и возвращения результата. как-то так: ```return Optional.ofNullable(reader.readLine()).orElse("0.0 0.0 none");```

Comment: К сожалению, данный метод мне не помог...

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял, вы хотите взять часть кода из страницы в интернете.
Для этого вам нужно подключить библиотеку jsoup.jar и потом вам нужно написать примерно такой код:

```
try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://ru.stackoverflow.com").get();
        Elements element = doc.select("head");
        String str = "";
        for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element el : element) {
            parm = el.attr("title");
        }
}catch(MalformedURLException e){
 Log.d("Veb", "doInBackground: error 1");
}
```

И еще не забудьте всю эту открыть в новом потоке.